# How to download image using Blackberry Webworks?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-webworks

I want to download an image from a server and save it to the SD card. I searched many sites but didn't find any solution. For reading and writing the file, I am using the following [File Reader & Writer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) code and it is working well. But I don't know how to save the file using Phonegap. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To save the file using PhoneGap, there is the  [FileTransfer API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)  which provides a method to download a file from a server to the device file system/SD card.

Using WebWorks, there is the [File API](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.io.file.html) which also offers a method ( saveFile() ) to save a file to the SD card.

Michelle Mendoza
Developer Relations
Research In Motion
@BlackBerryDev